# Running a sub-project main class

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `built.sbt` that references a child project's main class as its own main class:

```
lazy val akka = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(api)
  .dependsOn(api)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

lazy val api = project in file("api")

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

// This is referencing API code 
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("maslow.akka.cluster.node.ClusterNode")

artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  s"""${artifact.name}.${artifact.extension}"""
}

name in Universal := name.value

packageName in Universal := name.value
```

However, each time I run `sbt run` I get the following error:

```
> run
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mark/dev/Maslow-Akka/}api...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mark/dev/Maslow-Akka/}akka...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Running maslow.akka.cluster.node.ClusterNode
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: maslow.akka.cluster.node.ClusterNode
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: maslow.akka.cluster.node.ClusterNode
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
```

As I've been doing some research into the problem, I first switched to the project to `api` from `akka` and then opened up console. From there, it can't find the `maslow` package even though it most certainly exists. After that, I went into the `api` folder and ran `sbt console` and it accessed the aforementioned package just fine. After I do this, `sbt run` from the **akka** project works. Why?

The folder `api` is pulled in via `git read-tree`. There shouldn't be anything special about it. I'm using `sbt 0.13.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this line: `lazy val api = project in file("api")`

From the [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Dormant/Full-Configuration.html):

> When defining a dependency on another project, you provide a ProjectReference. In the simplest case, this is a Project object. (Technically, there is an implicit conversion Project => ProjectReference) This indicates a dependency on a project within the same build.

This indicates a dependency *within the same build*. Instead, what I needed was to use `RootProject` since `api` is an external build:

> It is possible to declare a dependency on a project in a directory separate from the current build, in a git repository, or in a project packaged into a jar and accessible via http/https. These are referred to as external builds and projects. You can reference the root project in an external build with RootProject:

In order to solve this problem, I removed the project declarations out of `build.sbt` into `project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val akka = Project("akka", file(".")).aggregate(api).dependsOn(api)
  lazy val api = RootProject(file("api"))
}
```

To be clear, the problem was that my `api` sub-project was a `ProjectRef` and not a `RootProject`.

Answer (score 2):

I think in a multi-project build a global line such as

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := ...
```

will just be swallowed without consequences, as it doesn't refer to any project.

Probably the following works:

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) in ThisBuild := ...
```

Or you add it to the root project's settings:

```
lazy val akka = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(api)
  .dependsOn(api)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    mainClass in (Compile, run) := ...
  )
```

Comment: Nope, still can't find it. The odd thing is if I change the project name from `api` to something else like `apii`, I get the following runtime exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Overlapping output directories:/Users/mark/dev/Maslow-Akka/api/target:
 ProjectRef(file:/Users/mark/dev/Maslow-Akka/,api)
 ProjectRef(file:/Users/mark/dev/Maslow-Akka/,apii)